# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.ops' has no attribute 'split_squeeze'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using lstm predictor for timeseries prediction..

```
regressor = skflow.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model(TIMESTEPS, RNN_LAYERS, DENSE_LAYERS))

validation_monitor = learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(X['val'], y['val'],
                                                      every_n_steps=PRINT_STEPS,
                                                      early_stopping_rounds=1000)

regressor.fit(X['train'], y['train'], monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

But while doing regressor.fit, i am getting the error as shown in Title, need help on this..

Comment: Can you please show the code of lstm model you made?

Comment: @heenabawa I just have used the code from: https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series and used the file lstm-for-epf.py, but as was getting error at line: 28, have changed the same to Estimator instead of TensorFlowEstimator, and getting error now at regressor.fit line...confused, can you help here?

Comment: The error may be due to variations in the tensorflow version. Please check the issues in the repository for it. https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series/issues/5

Comment: @heenabawa Already seen the issues, i have changed TensorFlowEstimator to Estimator and proceeded, but now my model is failing while doing regressor.fit, and it's failing with the error mentioned in the title i.e. module 'tensorflow.......' has no attribute 'split_squeeze'

Answer (score 3):

I understand that your code imports the `lstm_model` from the file [lstm_predictor.py](https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series/blob/master/lstm_predictor.py) when initializing your estimator. If so, the problem is caused by the following line:

```
x_ = learn.ops.split_squeeze(1, time_steps, X)
```

As the [README.md of that repo](https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series/blob/master/README.md) tells, the [Tensorflow API has changed significantly](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration). The function `split_squeeze` also seems to be removed from the module tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.ops. This issue [has been discussed](https://github.com/tgjeon/TensorFlow-Tutorials-for-Time-Series/issues/7) in that repository but no changes have been made in that repo since 2 years!

Yet, you can simply replace that function with [tf.unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack). So simply change the line as:

```
x_ =  tf.unstack(X, num=time_steps, axis=1)
```

With this I was able to get past the problem.